# How are those 4 formulas determined in codechef prime pattern?

Tags: c, coordinates

In the codechef primepattern question how those four fornulas are obtained for range of values of X and y?

[This problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/PRIMPATT)

This is what I am talking about These:

```
if(x-y>0 && x+y<=1) // south
{
sum=(y-1)*(4*y+2)+2;
sum+=x-y;
}
else if(x+y>1 && x-y>=0) // east
{
sum=(4*x-6)*x+2;
sum+=2*x-1;
sum+=x+y-1;
}
else if(x-y<0 && x+y>=0) // north
{
sum=(4*y-6)*y+2;
sum+=(y-1)*4+2;
sum+=y-x;
}
else if(x+y<0 &&x-y<=0) // west
{
sum=(8*x+12)*x/2+2;
sum+=(-x-1)*6+4;
sum+=-x-y;
}
return sum;
}
```

In short how are we calculating box number from given coordinates?

Comment: Are you talking about [this problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/PRIMPATT)? What formulas do you mean?

Comment: These-
  **  if(x-y>0 && x+y<=1) // south
    {
    sum=(y-1)*(4*y+2)+2;
    sum+=x-y;
    }
    else if(x+y>1 && x-y>=0) // east
    {
    sum=(4*x-6)*x+2;
    sum+=2*x-1;
    sum+=x+y-1;
    }
    else if(x-y<0 && x+y>=0) // north
    {
    sum=(4*y-6)*y+2;
    sum+=(y-1)*4+2;
    sum+=y-x;
    }
    else if(x+y<0 &&x-y<=0) // west
    {
    sum=(8*x+12)*x/2+2;
    sum+=(-x-1)*6+4;
    sum+=-x-y;
    }
    return sum;
    }**

Comment: I don't see that in the link. Is it from one of the successful submissions? Which one?

Comment: I am talking about this http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/7238506
for the north,west,east and south movement.